# RSeQC with multiQC and snakemake

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I want to include **RSeQC** results using **multiQC** in a **snakemake** workflows.
I have the issue that one of the **RSeQC** tool only reports a .r and a .pdf while it seems that **multiQC** requires a .txt input to create a plot.

Has anyone working code for **snakemake** that recover info from **RSeQC** into a **multiQC** rule.

As this is a combination of three tools, it is difficult to get support.

---

My code here of which only the geneBodyCoverage.txt RSeQC output is used (not the two .r outputs and especially junctionSaturation_plot.r of which there is nothing else than the .r and the png picture)

```python
rule multiqc_global:
"""
Aggregate all MultiQC reports
"""
  input:
    expand("intermediate/{smp}_fastqc.zip", smp=SAMPLES),
    expand("intermediate/merged_{smp}_fastqc.zip", smp=SAMPLES),
    expand("logs/star/{smp}_Log.final.out", smp=SAMPLES),
    expand("intermediate/{smp}.geneBodyCoverage.txt", smp=SAMPLES),
    expand("intermediate/{smp}.geneBodyCoverage.r", smp=SAMPLES),
    expand("intermediate/{smp}.junctionSaturation_plot.r", smp=SAMPLES),
  output:
    html = "results/global_multiqc.html",
    stats = "intermediate/global_multiqc_general_stats.txt"
  log:
    "logs/multiqc/global_multiqc.log"
  version: "1.0"
  shadow: "minimal"
  shell: 
    """
    # Run multiQC and keep the html report
    multiqc -n multiqc.html {input} 2> {log}
    mv multiqc.html {output.html}
    mv multiqc_data/multiqc_general_stats.txt {output.stats}
    """
```

Comment: Hi, if you want help with a combination of products it would be best to tag the question with them all. I see that there are no specific StackOverflow tags for the other two products, but please add existing tag(s) best describe them. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running at least one of RSeQC [modules supported by multiqc](https://multiqc.info/docs/#rseqc)? It doesn't look like `*.txt` file always; file used [depends on the module](https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC/blob/9e58729dcc28ebef974561fed0aee026a0f3b3a4/multiqc/utils/search_patterns.yaml#L419).

Comment: Hi @JeeYem; I tried to add th e.r file in the inputs too but only the QC from the txt file was generated.

Comment: Do you see any RSeQC results in your multiqc output? Or, do you not see all samples in your output? If latter, you could try `--dirs-depth` if the problem was due to same sample name. Also, try `--verbose` to see what multiqc is doing, which could tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Note - MultiQC uses different files from rseqc for different result types. For some, it uses the R scripts (as this is the only place to get the numbers from, aside from PDF). See the search patterns used here: https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC/blob/feb8c96b6320b23652307e5ffdc2bb994be112c1/multiqc/utils/search_patterns.yaml#L448-L470

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of anecdotal, since as @JeeYem pointed out in a comment, it could depend on what analysis you're running with RSeQC. Here's how I use the `read_distribution.py` analysis in snakemake, which generates a compatible file that MultiQC recognizes.

```
rule read_distribution:
    input:
        bam = "data/bam/{srr}.bam",
        bed = config["gencodeBED"]
    output:
        "qc/aligned/{srr}.read_distribution.txt"
    shell:
        """
        read_distribution.py -i {input.bam} -r {input.bed} &> {output}
        """
```

Basically, just redirect the stdout and err streams to a file.  Hopefully, it's a similar thing for the other RSeQC scripts.

Comment: Hi Mandy. Tried but my low credits are not allowing me to create tags. If you could create the tags i would apreciate

Comment: added my code above which only outputs one item out of the three coming from RSeQC